# calculate $R^2$ given $\hat{\sigma}_{\hat{\beta}_{i}}$

Tags: regression, mathematical-statistics, multiple-regression, linear

Statistics newbie here.

I have the following situation: where $\sigma^{2}$ is the variance of the disturbance for the model $y_{t}=\beta_{1}x_{t,1}+\beta_{2}x_{t,2}+\beta_{3}x_{t,3}$

$\hat{\sigma}^{2}=\frac{\hat{u}'\hat{u}}{T-k-1}=2,0896$ and

$\hat{\sigma}_{\hat{\beta}_{1}}=0,0887$ and $\hat{\sigma}_{\hat{\beta}_{2}}=0,1577$ and $\hat{\sigma}_{\hat{\beta}_{3}}=2,7552$

Furthermore: 
$\hat{\beta}_{1}=1,2909$,
$\hat{\beta}_{2}=0,1577$,
$\hat{\beta}_{3}=-0,1824$

I am asked to calculate $R^{2}$. I have only encountered problems until now to solve $R^{2}$ as $R^{2}=1-\frac{SQR}{SQT}$ but this is not given. How on earth do the $\hat{\sigma}_{\hat{\beta}_{i}}$'s help me?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the variance of the regression. $\hat{\sigma}^2$.

Since $\hat{u}'\hat{u} = SQR$. So we can say that $SQR = \hat{\sigma}^2 * (T-k-1)$. In your case $k=3$ because you have 3 parameters; so you need to remove the $-1$ from the denominator because you don't have the intercept term in your model. If you would have had 3 coefficients and also the intercept than you would have had $T-3-1$ ($T =$ number of observation that you have).

Once you have the sum of the squared residuals ($SQR$), you just need to find $SQT = \sum(y_i-\bar{y})^2$ and you are done.

Keep in mind two useful things:

- $SQR$ is a not correct estimator of the $\hat{\sigma}^2$, in fact you need to divide it by $T-k-1$.
- In the case of a model with only the intercept (null model) we have that $SQT = SQR$